# Getting A Database Locked Error When Using Golang and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, go

I'm experiencing a database locked error in this piece of code.
The thing is I already wrote pretty similar code to this and I wasn't getting any errors.
But now when I run it, I get a **Database Locked Error** with the error code 5.
The error occurs on the `tx.Commit()` statement.

Here's the code itself:

```
type UserRepository struct {
    db *driver.QuestionlyDb
}

/*
Creates a new user sql driver that executes user sql statements on the sql driver.
*/
func CreateUserRepository(db *driver.QuestionlyDb) *UserRepository {
    return &UserRepository{db: db}
}

/*
Create a new user row in the database.
*/
func (ur *UserRepository) CreateUser(u *User) error {
    tx, err := ur.db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    stmt, err := tx.Prepare(`INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);`)
    if err != nil {
        _ = tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }

    defer stmt.Close()

    _, err = stmt.Exec(u.GetID(), u.GetEmail(), u.GetPassword(), u.GetUsername())
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }

    if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

The database connection is created in the following way:

```
type QuestionlyDb struct {
    *sql.DB
}

/*
Creates a new database connection.
*/
func CreateDatabase() (*QuestionlyDb, error) {
    db, err := connectToDb()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    sqlDb := &QuestionlyDb{db}
    return sqlDb, nil
}

// TODO: Set db name as env variable
func connectToDb() (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./questionly.db")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return db, err
}
```

Comment: `Database Locked` seems to imply that the database is being used by another application, or your application does not have permissions to modify.

Can you read from the database using SELECT ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I can event insert data into the table.

Comment: Try running `stmt.Close()` before the `tx.Commit()` (currently your use of `defer` means that the statement is still open when you commit).

Comment: From your drivername `"sqlite3"` it looks like you're using mattn/go-sqlite. For SQLite specifically, https://pkg.go.dev/zombiezen.com/go/sqlite might also be interesting. In stead of one connection like in your example, you can have a connection pool. Not sure if it's related to your problem but FYI. Also: modernc for pure go driver (without cgo).